# Liskov, Rectangles, Squares, and Null Objects

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, solid, liskov-substitution

I keep thinking I have my head wrapped around the Liskov Substitution Principle, and then I realize I don't. Here's where I've gathered from
StackExchange:

1. Subclassing Square from Rectangle violates LSP because if you change the width of a Square the height changes too.
2. Null Objects don't violate LSP.

Those seem to contradict each other to me. If this is bad:

```
square.setWidth(40);
square.setHeight(50);
width = square.getWidth(); // Returns 50 instead of 40. Liskov hates that.
```

Then why isn't this bad?

```
nullRectangle.setWidth(40);
nullRectangle.setHeight(50);
width = nullRectangle.getWidth(); // Returns 0 or null. Isn't that worse?
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: LSP relies on the idea of *contracts*. If a null object doesn't fit the contract (in this case `setWidth(n); setHeight(m); assert(getWidth() == n);`), then it does violate LSP.

Comment: Your use of getters and setters to reach through the object and access its internal data is the source of the problem. Check out [this article](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2073723/core-java/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html).

Comment: @AndrewPiliser -- This feels like a silly question, but could I explicitly define the contract of Rectangle to be "if you change one side, the other side may or may not change, depending on what kind of Rectangle it is"? I'm sure there are many reasons this would be a bad idea, but would it specifically violate LSP?

Comment: @M.Christian You could define it that way, and it wouldn't violate LSP, but it would violate the principle of least surprise. You'd have to make sure everyone else working on the code understands the contract, and that would be easiest to do by not calling it a Rectangle anymore.

Comment: So, for my edification, if the square and rectangle had `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` because it extended a base class `Shape2D`, and the square and rectangle had specific setters (like `setSize()` for square and separate set hight/width for rectangle)--then we would be OK for Liskov Substitution Principle?

Comment: @Berin Yes, it would.. but that does not mean you can use these to calculate anything about the shape.  It just indicates the maximum horizontal and vertical span your shape has on a 2D plane.  You could also have a getPerimeter and getArea for your Shape2D and still retain Liskov substitution.  Basically all methods you add in Shape2D has to be callable AND meaningful when all you know about the instance is that it is a 2D shape.  Setting the height and width could however be problematic as these could have different effect on the various shape implementations.

Comment: @AndrewPiliser The principle of least surprise is a good principle, but somewhat subjective. There's a more concrete, objective problem with changing the contract to "the other side may or may not change": you've *lost information* about the state of the object after a call to `setX`. Under the old contract, you knew with certainty that a call to `setWidth` wouldn't affect `getHeight`. It's always possible to weaken contracts, but a list that may or may not store the values it's given isn't of much use to anyone.

Comment: @KaseySpeakman Subclassing square from rectangle results in LSP violation, as pointed out by the OP. A satisfying way to solve this “apparent paradox” while retaining the idea that a square is a special rectangle is to conclude that the classes we are provided do NOT model rectangles and squares. In geometry a rectangle is not something that changes, two distinct rectangles are just two distinct rectangles. Thus adding mutability to the rectangle turns it into something more than a rectangle, it is actually a function parametrising rectangles together with a distinguished point. 1/2

Comment: @KaseySpeakman What the OP implements is actually a DeformableRectangle (resp. a DeformableSquare), which we can think of as a particular Rectangle (resp. Square) together with the information that it evolves in a “space of all rectangles” (resp. “space of all squares”) – and with the presence of this extra bit of information, we can easily explain why a “DeformableRectangle” is not a special case of ”DeformableSquare”.  If we consider immutable classes “Rectangle” and ”Square” then the “apparent paradox” vanishes and there is no objection subclassing “Square” from “Rectangle” 2/2

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald I agree with your analysis wrt Deformable. However, it seemed the goal was to explain/resolve the LSP violation. You might be able to subclass Square from Rectangle with immutable classes, but you would have to force Square to fit Rectangle's implementation details (length and height instead of sideLength), which (in non-toy examples) can make for brittle code due to tight coupling.

Comment: @Newtopian, I had the getters in `Shape2d` and the setters in the subclasses.  I think we are saying the same thing, but just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @KaseySpeakman Rather than really addressing directly OP's problem (who seems more concerned by the NULL-object) I made a side comment. Is the point you make reminiscent of the “only virtual classes are allowed to have subclasses”-discipline? Or is it an avatar of the emphasis on behaviours rather than attributes that OO programs (should) have.

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald My point is more an artifact of doing it the way the OP did some years ago but to a further degree, and suffering the maintenance consequences to this very day. Behavior and protecting its own state is what makes an Object. Using "objects" as state hierarchies is just another form of procedurally mutating a shared state. All the ways a shared state can get mutated gets harder to keep in your head over time. Sometimes exposing data is the right call, but it's not a good starting point.

Comment: For the record, since the "best" examples of LSP all involve fairly academic discussions of Circles and Squares, I've concluded that the LSP is one of the least important programming principles.  It certainly doesn't belong in the "top 5" as stressed by SOLID.  Frankly, I think the S and O parts of SOLID are overrated too.  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have found is simply edge case where Null object might not be good solution.

The point of `null object` is to make behavior same as if you checked for `null` beforehand.

In your case, if this code is expected behavior:

```
Rectangle nullRectangle = null;
int width = 0;
if (nullRectangle != null)
{
    nullRectangle.setWidth(40);
    nullRectangle.setHeight(50);
    width = nullRectangle.getWidth();
}
// width is 0 if nullRectangle is null
```

Ten `null object` as described in your code is logical substitute.

But the idea of having "null rectangle" doesn't make much sense from modeling perspective. Null object really is only usable as implementation of abstractions, where calling a method doesn't mean the caller is always expecting something. If caller of any method of the abstraction sees "no operation" or "no data returned" as valid result, then `null object` can be used. If instead a non-zero value is expected as return, then null object truly violates LSP.

Answer (score 2):

I think the Rectangle/Square problem is a result of a misguided domain analysis.

**Mathematical rectangles / squares**

From math, we all know that squares are special cases of rectangles, which we translate to `Square` being a subclass of `Rectangle`, and that's fine as long as we stay with the mathematical concept of rectangle and square **which doesn't include changing width or height of the object**. For immutable shapes, the inheritance model complies with the Liskov principle.

**Mutable program objects**

As soon as we introduce a setter, e.g. `setHeight()`, the mathematical analogy no longer holds, and we must do a new analysis.

What does `setHeight(50)` mean? When we see this in a `Rectangle` class, we all suppose that the width stays the same, so it modifies the shape's aspect ratio. And that's an operation that, when applied to a square, results in a non-square rectangle. So a `Square.setHeight()` method can't conform to the `Rectangle`-inspired contract as it should modify the object's class from `Square` to `Rectangle` (which is impossible in all programming languages I know).

So, having a mutable `Square` class inherit from `Rectangle` violates Liskov.

The source of evil here is mutability. If `setHeight()` were to return a fresh instance instead of changing the state of the original instance, we could solve the situation. Then calling `setHeight()` on a `Square` could easily return a `Rectangle` with the new dimensions. It could even inherit the implementation from `Rectangle`.

Answer (score 1):

There's already an accepted answer, but I wanted to point out a couple of things.

Objects should have a behavior which they perform. Otherwise there is little reason to use one over a struct. Your example objects have no behavior whatsoever, only data which you have made more complicated to access via getters and setters. Your example violates Liskov mainly because it is not object-oriented anyway. It is procedurally reading and writing data with a specific structure.

I want to also mention that "Null Objects" do not mean `null` pointers. They mean an implementation of the class with a default behavior. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29MAL8pJImQ).

So what could LSP look like?

If I think of Shape2D in terms of what behavior I want it to do for me, one thing that comes to mind is area calculation. Because this will be different across shapes.

```
public class Shape2D
{
    public virtual double GetArea() { return 0.0; }
}
```

Here, I am using Shape2D as its own Null Object -- a shape that has no area. It can be extended by subclassing and overriding `GetArea()`.

> Returning `double` as the area is a questionable choice. Because there are other implications with area, like the unit of measure or that it can be infinite. Maybe an Area class should be created too if this were production code.

So let's create some implementations of 2-dimensional area-having things.

```
public class Square : Shape2D
{
    private double _sideLength;
    public Square(double sideLength) { _sideLength = sideLength; }
    public override double GetArea()
        { return _sideLength ^ 2 }
}

public class Rectangle : Shape2D
{
    private double _length;
    private double _height;
    public Rectangle(double length, double height) { ... }
    public override double GetArea()
        { return _length * _height; }
}

public class Circle : Shape2D
{
    private double _radius;
    public Circle(double radius) { _radius = radius; }
    public override double GetArea()
        { return Math.Pi * (_radius ^ 2); }
}
```

Now at this point, you might be wondering. "Why don't I just calculate the area in the constructor?" or "Why not just create a static method for different area calculations?" Well, what about complex 2D shapes? Like a concave octagon defined by vectors? Maybe the particular shape implementation is computationally expensive to calculate area? I think ultimately it requires some intuition to determine which way is correct. But in the example here, we are calculating it only when requested.

In the original question, you changed the width of the Rectangle by altering private data about the rectangle. But here, you would create a `new` Rectangle with different dimensions.

So this follows LSP, because for any method which takes a `Shape2D`, you could pass in a `Square`, `Shape2D` (Null Object), or any shape you might implement in the future like `ConcaveOctagon` without the method knowing it.

Comment: It's not intended as working code, it's a common bit of toy code used when discussing Liskov, as in http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/squarerectangle.aspx. Given that it's used as a common example of a Liskov violation, I don't think the lack of more functionality is the problem.

And I know null objects aren't null pointers. I feel like you're trying to answer questions I'm not asking.

Comment: @M.Christian There are many common examples which are wrong-headed thinking on OO. They led me astray for years, too. I *am* answering a different question from what you asked, because your question has a faulty premise. OO and Liskov are not about data hierarchies, which is what you create by inheritance of getters and setters.

Comment: @M.Christian Also note in the example you linked, the author concludes that a correct implementation would have a Shape base class which does not include the dimensions as part of the contract. "The base class would not include properties for Height and Width, instead allowing the dimensions of different shapes to be handled by their implementations. A Rectangle subclass would have Height and Width properties and a Square may have a single Size value."

Comment: The last time I saw a double XORed with 2 was in some air collision avoidance code from NASA, so you're in good company, sort of. Fortunately it never flew on our planes.

Answer (score 1):

The "trick" of the classic Square-Rectangle LSP problem is that if we define a rectangle as an object that must satisfy the contract...

```
rectangle.setWidth(40);
rectangle.setHeight(50);
assert(rectangle.getWidth() == 40);
```

...then extend it to a square, then we violate that contract. This is because we are mixing up a custom definition of a rectangle and a classical definition. As such, we are trying to make the classical definition fit into a custom definition, which doesn't work. In essence, it is a parlour trick intended to make you think about sub-type behaviour and contractual obligations. We could just as easily show that the above assertion of a Rectangle object fails for even a rectangle with some cunning rewording:

```
rectangle.setTopEdgeLength(40);
rectangle.setBottomEdgeLength(50);
assert(rectangle.getTopEdgeLength() == 40);
```

Anyhow, enough of the riddles, let's have a look at the...

**Classical Definition**

Correctly put, squares and rectangles are both types of quadrilaterals, a quadrilateral being a polygon with 4 edges and 4 vertices. Classically, a square *is* a rectangle, but let's have a look at the Wikipedia definitions of a rectangle and a square:

- **Rectangle**: A quadrilateral with four right angles
- **Square**: A quadrilateral with four right angles and four equal sides

Notice something there? The only commonalities between a rectangle and a square are that both are quadrilaterals, and both have four right angles. No mention at all of rules around the length of the sides, as these are *derived* from the contract, not part of the contract. We can demonstrate this with some simple logical statements:

- if a shape is a quadrilateral and the shape has four right angles, then opposite sides will be of equal length
- if a shape is quadrilateral and the shape has four right angles and four equal sides, then the length of any side will be equal to the length any other side (this one is actually a tautology)

If we want to maintain the classical definition of rectangles and squares *and* represent them in code with the `setWidth()` and `setHeight()` methods in place, then the contract needs to be:

```
square.setWidth(40);
square.setHeight(50);
assert(square.isQuadrilateral());
assert(square.hasFourRightAngles());
```

Whether the width is still what we set it in line 1 is irrelevant, as that rule does not form part of the contractual obligations of the parent object Rectangle.

---

To sum up, the initial problem is one of contractual definitions. I'm not saying you shouldn't have a Rectangle object that satisfies `rectangle.setWidth(40); rectangle.setHeight(50); assert(rectangle.getWidth() == 40);`, but if you define your Rectangle object in that fashion, then when you extend it you need to ensure that the contract is still valid, otherwise you violate LSP.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two pitfalls in this example.

The first one is already pointed out in comments: inheritance based on internal structure is used, and [it shouldn't be](https://medium.com/@wrong.about/inheritance-based-on-internal-structure-is-evil-7474cc8e64dc): it breaks object's encapsulation, it's fragile, it's procedural after all.

So the solution seems to use subtyping, like that:

```
interface IRectangle
{
    public function setWidth($width);

    public function setHeight($height);
}

class Rectangle implements IRectangle
{
    private $width;
    private $height;

    public function setWidth($width)
    {
        $this->width = $width;
    }

    public function setHeight($height)
    {
        $this->height = $height;
    }
}

class Square implements IRectange
{
    private $side;

    public function setWidth($width)
    {
        $this->side = $width;
    }

    public function setHeight($height)
    {
        $this->side = $height;
    }
}
```

But there is the same contract violation.

So here is the second pitfall. **In this context**, characterized by objects' responsibilities, there should be two different abstractions, represented with two different interfaces: `IRectangle` and `ISquare`.

So it seems that this notorious example is just a logical puzzle, the one where there is some logical error but no one knows where it is. What are the rationals behind saying "square is a special case of a rectangle"? In what context is it a special case? What is the exact use case when a square acts like a rectangle? Probably there are some, but definitely it's not the one where rectangle's width is changed while height stays the same. So first of all this stupid example violates common sense, then OOP, and only after that it violates LSP.